# AWS Lambda function execution does not show the results with executing successfully

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

I am currently using AWS Lambda to get csv datasets from S3 to RDS Mysql tables. 
I tested a lambda function that I created which executed perfectly, but some reason the datasets were not inserted to the tables of the database in RDS.

It might be caused by triggers or the part other than Lambda, but I am having a difficult time finding what is the issue here since I am very new to AWS Lambda.

Any suggestions or recommendations will be very appreciated.

Here is the Lambda function:

```
import sys
import logging
import rds_config
import pymysql
import numpy as np
import csv
import pandas as pd
import mysql.connector
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import boto3
import botocore



Bucket_Name = 'ceo-project'

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

name = rds_config.db_username
password = rds_config.db_password
db_name = rds_config.db_name
rds_host = rds_config.rds_host

logger = logging.getLogger()

logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
try:
    conn = pymysql.connect(host=rds_host, user=name, passwd=password, port =3306, db=db_name, connect_timeout=30)

except pymysql.MySQLError as e:
    logger.error("ERROR: Unexpected error: Could not connect to MySQL instance.")
    logger.error(e)
    sys.exit()

logger.info("SUCCESS: Connection to RDS MySQL instance succeeded")
engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://'+name+':'+password+'@'+rds_host+':3306'+'/'+db_name)

def handler(event, context):

    def S3_get_csv(Bucket_Name, Folder_Name,i):

        if isinstance(prefix, str):
            kwargs['Prefix'] = prefix

        while True: 
            resp = s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket=Bucket_Name, Prefix=Folder_Name+'/')
            latest = max(contents, key=lambda x: x['LastModified'])
            try:
                contents = resp['Contents']

            except KeyError:
                return

            for obj in contents:
                key = obj['Key']
                if key.startswith(prefix):
                    yield obj


        try:
            s3.Bucket(Bucket_Name).download_file(latest['Key'],latest['Key'].split(sep='/')[1])
            df = pd.read_csv(latest['Key'].split(sep='/')[1])
            df.to_sql(name=table_list[i], con=engine, if_exists = 'append', index=False,chunksize=10000,method='multi')
        except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e:
            if e.resp['Error']['Code'] == "404":
                print("The object does not exist.")
            else:
                raise

    def get_matching_s3_keys(bucket, prefix='', suffix=''):
        for obj in get_matching_s3_objects(bucket, prefix):
            yield obj['Key']


    Folder_list = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7']
    table_list = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g']
    for i in range(0,7):
        S3_get_csv(Bucket_Name,Folder_list[i],i)

    return "CSV files inserted to RDS"
```

Comment: Was this a SQL transaction (perhaps implicitly) and was it committed?

Comment: @jarmod I would say it could be a SQL transaction because I want to insert each of the csv files to individual tables of the database in RDS.

Comment: I think you need to find out what your DB connection library does. Some will implicitly preface your calls with a transaction and require *you* to explicitly commit. If you don't commit, then everything is rolled back, which fits your symptoms.

Comment: @jarmod Thank you for your comment. It could be a silly question but, how can I commit it or even how can I monitor that it was committed? I am using MySQL Workbench, btw.

Comment: SQL Workbench is a client query tool. It has nothing to do with your application. You are using Pandas DF to_sql which takes a SQLAlchemy engine object. Take a look at the documentation for SQLAlchemy to find a way to manage transactions when using an engine. The docs clearly show how you can do it with a connection, but not with an engine object. Ref: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_transaction.html. It might be as simple as `sess = Session(bind=engine)` before calling `to_sql(...)` and then calling `sess.commit()` afterwards.